# Have OpenERP export reports in CSV format rather than XML

Tags: python, csv, export, report, odoo

I'm currently trying to have OpenERP (version 7) export some data to a CSV file instead of a XML file. The company I work for uses the so-called "Aged Partner Balance"-module which generates a PDF file from XML/RML data. I would like to add the option to export this data to CSV also, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The Aeroo documentation suggests that it's possible to use the engine to output CSV but after a couple of days of experimenting, I cannot say that I've found a way to do so.

Currently the module returns the following:

```
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
        'report_name': 'account.aged_trial_balance',
        'datas': data
    }
```

I was wondering if it were possible to change this to something like:

```
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report.csv',
        'report_name': 'account.aged_trial_balance',
        'datas': data
    }
```

Obviously, this is way too simple and won't work but I was wondering if something similar might actually be possible. I really get the idea that the Aeroo report allows for this behaviour but I just can't find out how.

Any help would be highly appreciated. If you have a completely different strategy, I'd of course love to hear about that too.